# Vector graphics editor for Linux

Tags: linux, image-editor, vector-graphics, svg

Which is the best vector graphics editor for Linux? The most popular is [Inkscape](https://inkscape.org/en/). I have tried working with Inkscape, but feel that ease of working is not great. Comparatively, I have tried working with Microsoft Powerpoint and found it much easier.

Therefore, I used to make just graphics alone in Microsoft PowerPoint and export as vector graphic. But the fact of booting another OS, just for drawing is not a good idea.

What are some good vector graphics software the users recommend for Linux?

I am a mechanical engineer. So mostly, I would be drawing line based 2D or isometric (3D) illustrations.

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! We will need much more information to give good recommendations here – asking for "a tool like X" is never giving enough details, even if linked. You should always list your requirements explicitly. Please see [How to ask for an alternative to some software](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/48/185) and the questions linked to it for details.

Comment: Long time since you've worked with Inkscape. Give it another try as they have now reached quite a stable and workable version 1.3.

Answer (score 1):

[Krita](https://krita.org/) has vector graphic mode. It lacks features comparing to Inkscape, but is more user friendly. If you are Ok with powerpoint then Krita would probably be sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

I would also checkout Apache OpenOffice Draw. It is very easy to use and runs on most platforms. It supports both 2D and 3D illustrations.

## [Apache OpenOffice Draw](http://www.openoffice.org/product/draw.html)

> Draw, part of the Apache OpenOffice suite, is a graphics editor that
>   gives you the tools to communicate with visuals and diagrams. With a
>   maximum page size of 300cm by 300cm, Draw is powerful tool for
>   posters, graphs, charts, and more.
>
> [image: OpenOffice Draw UI]